# Is there a way to specify which variable to use in ember relationship

Tags: ember.js

After specifying the relationship between

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment')
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  post: DS.belongsTo('post')
});
```

But what it does is it **accepts integer id in 'post'** and **an array of integers in 'comments'** can anyone please tell me how to use **any other variable for the reference** like name or title instead of array.

Comment: It's not an integer ... it's a reference to the object (i.e. the array contains the objects which are referenced by their numbers).

Answer (score 0):

With the associations, they are referencing the ember models not their specific types. So in this case the comments in the post model are just references to the individual comment ember objects